# Ionic 4 - Google Maps URL: Why latitude and longitude do not transform to a direction name? (only iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, query-string, ionic4

I am working in a Ionic 4 application and I am re directing my application to Google Maps, building a URL like this:

> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=3.4718011,-76.529981&destination=3.45371,-76.516606&travelmode=driving

and opening it with `window.open(url, '_system');` function.

When I open this URL in Android, (see the Android image attached), the latitude and longitude change for an approximate direction, but in iOS it is not happening. How can I make that iOS shows the approximate direction? it is happening in Google maps app and Google Maps web opened in Safary app and Chrome app (in the iPhone). Thanks!
[Differences between displayed route (Android and iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEBF8.jpg)